# .desktop files not visible on Desktop screen

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, .desktop, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and whenever i try to copy .desktop files to the desktop they are not visible on the desktop screen although they are when i do "show Desktop in files". What seems to be the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the Gnome shell extension "Desktop Icons"? If not, you won't see any icons on your desktop. You can enable it in the Gnome extensions app or with this command:

```
gnome-extensions enable desktop-icons@csoriano
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all hidden files in a folder, go to that folder and either click the view options button in the toolbar and pick Show Hidden Files, or press `Ctrl+H.`

[image]

You will see all hidden files, along with regular files that are not hidden.

To hide these files again, either click the view options button in the toolbar and pick Show Hidden Files or press `Ctrl+H` again.

The desktop screen doesn't show hidden files; that is simply the main working space and place where the icons for the files and folders on your hard drive is displayed. Files manager gives you the ability to hide and unhide files at will.